# Is there a library available to draw a dataflow diagram using JSON input

Tags: javascript, json

I have huge json data and I would like to show it in a pictorial representation similar to the data flow digram below. Is there any framework or library I can use to do that?

I have tried using [AnswerMiner](https://www.answerminer.com/) but that doesn't show the result in a graph/pictorial format.

[image]

Comment: Not the tree view but a image like I attached,  dont know what exactly to call this.

Comment: Add  a sample of your json record.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like [Data Flow Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram).

If you need a commercial version, check out [gojs](https://gojs.net/latest/index.html).

For open source library, check out [jsplumb](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb).

I have not used any of these libraries, but they seem to do what you intend to do. You may want to include a sample of your json file in your question to get a more precise answer. Most probably, your json data file needs to be converted to the format expected by these libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the schema for your JSON-format data, you might need to do some pre-processing.  But once you do you could easily create something that looks like https://gojs.net/latest/samples/stateChart.html.  Or look at https://gojs.net/latest/samples/index.html to get an idea of some other renderings that might be of greater interest to you.